# how to retrieve data from Parse database and display in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, database, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve data that I have sent to a database through a different website. I am using a search bar to query the address, once successful, I would like to display the rest of the objects in the row on the page under the search bar. I am having trouble with the syntax that will display the parameters of the object.

javascript:

```
Parse.initialize('###########');
databaseURI = 'mongodb://############';
var aptQuery = new Parse.Query(Apartment.address)
aptQuery.find({
  success:function(foundApts){
    console.log(foundApts);
  }, error: function(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
})
console.log(savedApartment);
```

html:

```
    <input type="search" id="aptSearch" placeholder="Address" >
```

Comment: Which object parameters you want to get ?

Comment: I want to get apartment.name apartment.address, apartment.state, apartment.city, and apartment.zipcode

Comment: Oh no problem, see my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a field from your object you can write:

```
appartement.get("city");
```

To set it in your HTML code:

```
document.getElementById('aptSearch').value = appartement.get("city");
```

So your code can seems like this:

```
var aptQuery = new Parse.Query("Apartment")
aptQuery.find({
  success:function(foundApts){
    console.log(foundApts);
    for (var i in foundApts) {
        var appartement = foundApts[I];
        document.getElementById('aptSearch').value = appartement.get("city");
    }
  }, error: function(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
})
```

Comment: can i set that to a variable that I would be able to call in my html?

Comment: @cwa I have update my answer, I hope that solve your problem 

Comment: I did that and it is returning errors in the console. saying apartment is not defined, XMLHttpRequest cannot load and POST 410 (gone). I have the correct app id and database URL as well as the parse src in a separate script tag

Comment: You query is in JavaScript client ?

Comment: I emailed you julien

Comment: It still does not let me access my API. My api id and Database uri are both correct. Not sure what I am missing. I am reading through the parse server website and cannot find what I need

Comment: You have any access to your API ? From the client

Comment: Yea i have a submission site, that sends data to my api, which is successful. I get No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. when I try to search from my client side.

Comment: Can you show me the initialisation of your client ?

Comment: how do you mean?